# Compile LESS with different variables using grunt

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, less

I have HTML template based on Bootstrap, that have different colors
   (red, green, etc.). Colors are changing using `@brand` variable in
   `variables.less`. Now I go to this file, change variable, compile
   less files, go to compiled css files directory and rename CSS file
   according it's color (`red.css`, `green.css`, etc.). And I make this
   steps 7 times (7 colors = 7 steps).

Can I automate this process using grunt or something like this and how?

Comment: @seven-phases-max its the best answer ever

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [grunt-contrib-less](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-less) you can overwrite any variable. So you can automate your process by doing something like the following -

```
module.exports = function(grunt) { 
    grunt.initConfig({  

        less: {

                /** Red**/
                red: {
                    options: {
                        paths: ["less/"],
                        modifyVars: {
                            brand : 'red'
                        }
                    },
                    files: {
                        "css/red.css": "less/style.less"
                    }
                },
                /** Red**/
                green: {
                    options: {
                        paths: ["less/"],
                        modifyVars: {
                            brand : 'green'
                        }
                    },
                    files: {
                        "css/green.css": "less/style.less"
                    }
                },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');


    grunt.registerTask('default', ['less:red','less:green']);
}
```

change the config based on your file structures and add as many item as you need - I made 2 items

Comment: Any idea how to achieve this with gulp?

Comment: @Aajahid, i am looking for this kind of configuration in SASS. Any idea please? what basically exectation here is equivalent of modifyVars in SASS.

Answer (score 2):

When dynamically generating your your task you can create a more DRY version of the accepted answer by @Aajhid, see also: [Run Grunt tasks recursively over array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784810/run-grunt-tasks-recursively-over-array)

Your `Gruntfile.js` can look as follows:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  'use strict';

var TaskArray = [];
var tasks = [];
var colors = ['red','green','blue'];

colors.forEach(function(color) { 
        tasks[color] = {options: {sourceMap:true, modifyVars:{}},files:{} };
        tasks[color]['options']['modifyVars']['brand']= color;
        tasks[color]['files']['dist/' + color + '.css'] = 'less/project.less';
        TaskArray.push('less:' + color);
}); 
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.config('less',tasks);
grunt.registerTask( 'default', TaskArray );  
};
```