# Run Grunt tasks recursively over array

Tags: gruntjs, less

I have to build a number of css files for different locations and browsers all delineated by a flag in the file name.  For instance:

- styles-en.css
- styles-jp.css
- styles-ie.css

The content differences are handled by LESS boolean variables @isIE, @isEN, @isJA, @isDE etc. that match the file naming pattern.

I would love to automate building these different versions by passing Grunt an array of flags then for each:

- set the variable for LESS
- run LESS compiler for all files in a folder (same for all languages)
- use the variable in the exported file name

[This answer spells out the iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198682/compile-less-with-different-variables-using-grunt) but is there a tidier method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [How to configure sourceMaps for LESS using Grunt when there is more than one file in your project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836427/how-to-configure-sourcemaps-for-less-using-grunt-when-there-is-more-than-one-fil/26758062) and [Compile LESS to multiple CSS files, based on variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751574/compile-less-to-multiple-css-files-based-on-variable-value/26752074) you can create your `Gruntfile.js` as follows:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  'use strict';

var TaskArray = [];
var tasks = [];
//var lessVariable = '';
var languages = ['de','en','nl'];

languages.forEach(function(language) { 
        tasks[language] = {options: {sourceMap:true, modifyVars:{}},files:{} };
        tasks[language]['options']['sourceMapFilename'] = 'dist/' + language + '.map.css';
        tasks[language]['options']['modifyVars']['is' + language.toUpperCase()]= true;
        tasks[language]['files']['dist/' + language + '.css'] = 'less/project.less';
        TaskArray.push('less:' + language);
}); 
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.config('less',tasks);
grunt.registerTask( 'default', TaskArray );  
};
```

The above dynamically creates your tasks by using the `languages` array. Your boolean variables are change by the `modifyVars` option of grunt-contrib-less, see also http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-modify-variables.

When your `less/project.less` contains the following code:

```
@isDE: false;
@isNL: false;
@isEN: false;

.m when (@isDE) {
language: de;
}

.m when (@isNL) {
language: nl;
}

.m when (@isEN) {
language: en;
}

.m();
```

Running `grunt && cat dist/nl.css` should output like that shown beneath:

```
Running "less:de" (less) task
File dist/de.map.css created.
File dist/de.css created

Running "less:en" (less) task
File dist/en.map.css created.
File dist/en.css created

Running "less:nl" (less) task
File dist/nl.map.css created.
File dist/nl.css created

Done, without errors.
.m {
  language: nl;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=dist/nl.map.css */
```